# Slow Query not using index in one of the tables

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

My Rails table structure is like this: a `User` has_many `Contact`s, which have one `Reservation` each, which have many `ReservationNotes` each.

I'm trying to get all the `ReservationNote`s for the contacts belonging to a User (in the example, user.id is 1).

The query works, but is very slow and doesn't use indexes (possible_keys is empty for the table `reservations`), but I don't have enough experience with EXPLAIN and even tough I added all the possible indexes (indicated below) the query is still not fast enough:

```
=> EXPLAIN for: SELECT `reservation_notes`.* FROM `reservation_notes` INNER JOIN `reservations` ON `reservations`.`id_hash` = `reservation_notes`.`reservation_id_hash` INNER JOIN `contacts` ON `contacts`.`id_hash` = `reservations`.`contact_id_hash` WHERE `contacts`.`user_id` = 1 */
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                               | key                                            | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | reservations      | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                        | NULL                                           | NULL    | NULL | 5994 |    100.0 | NULL                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contacts          | NULL       | ref  | index_contacts_on_id_hash,index_contacts_on_user_id,index_contacts_on_user_id_and_read_by_user,index_contacts_on_user_id_and_blocked,index_contacts_on_user_id_and_read_by_user_and_blocked | index_contacts_on_id_hash                      | 767     | func |    1 |      5.0 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | reservation_notes | NULL       | ref  | index_reservation_notes_on_reservation_id_hash                                                                                                                                              | index_reservation_notes_on_reservation_id_hash | 576     | func |    1 |    100.0 | Using index condition              |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here are my indexes:

On table `contacts` (4 million records):

- index_contacts_on_user_id
- index_contacts_on_id_hash UNIQUE

On table `reservations` (6000 records):

- index_reservations_on_contact_id_hash
- index_reservations_on_id_hash UNIQUE

On table `reservation_notes` (2000 records):

- index_reservation_notes_on_id_hash UNIQUE
- index_reservation_notes_on_reservation_id_hash

So have I reached the limit of performance on Mysql, not being able to return a user's contacts reservation_notes any faster than 350ms?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  n.*
    FROM  `reservation_notes` AS n
    INNER JOIN  `reservations` AS r  ON r.`id_hash` = n.`reservation_id_hash`
    INNER JOIN  `contacts` AS c  ON c.`id_hash` = r.`contact_id_hash`
    WHERE  c.`user_id` = 1 */
```

A guess:  `user_id` is `VARCHAR`??  It should be `INT` (or some other numeric datatype).  And `c` (Contacts) needs `INDEX(user_id)`.  (Please don't use those awfully long names for indexes; it clutters things unnecessarily.)

That would let the Optimizer *start* with `c` and do the filtering (`user_id=1`) *first*.

Also, provide `INDEX(user_id, id_hash)`, in this order.  That will make the index "covering".  This means that the processing can be done entirely in the index's BTree, without touching the Data BTree.  This is an extra optimizaiton.

Then `r` (Reservations) needs `INDEX(contact_id_hash, id_hash)`.  The first column is for reaching into the table.  The extra column is to make it "covering".

Then `n` (Notes) needs `INDEX(reservation_id_hash)`, which you apparently have.

With these changes, `EXPLAIN` will list the table in a more optimal order:  c, r, n.  (I prefer to write `JOINs` in the order that the Optimizer will perform the query.  However, the Optimizer will rearrange the tables as it sees fit.)

When you get millions of rows, you may find that "hashes" slow things down.  But that is another topic.